# Como obter status code HTTP de consulta cURL

Tags: php, libcurl, http-status

Tenho esse cURL que me traz um array como resposta, preciso saber qual o status code http dessa requisição:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => $merchantApiHost.'/authentication/v1.0/oauth/token',
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'grantType=client_credentials&clientId='.$clientId.'&clientSecret='.$clientSecret,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$retorno = json_decode($response, true);

$accessToken = $retorno['accessToken'];
```

Comment: Você pode achar [aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php), `curl_getinfo`, com segundo parâmetro `CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE`.

Comment: @Benilson Perfeito. Adicionei `$httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)` que me traz o code, agora consigo trabalhar com if: de acordo com o $httpcode

Comment: Veja se te ajuda [Getting HTTP code in PHP using curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797680/getting-http-code-in-php-using-curl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize a função `curl_getinfo()` antes do `curl_close($curl);`

Esta função vai retornar uma array com diversas informações sobre o curl que você realizou.

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init("https://www.google.com/");
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
echo $info["http_code"];
?>
```